# 60/70's novel: virus kills all humanity except genius people; two survivors try to get to the West Coast

Tags: story-identification, novel

Written 40 or 50 years ago - a virus kills off all in the world except genius IQ people - two characters enter the picture:  one is a teenage boy who is a world class pianist; the other is a girl of similar age who is in a coma for a few weeks.  They leave and try to get to the West Coast, I think, and invent a vehicle that can ride railroad rails.  That's all I can remember.  It was excellent.  The boy is full of real groaner puns.

The author was introduced as the next Heinlein (along with a lot of others, I suppose).  I don't know anything more - if he became famous, died young - just dunno.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: "Invent a vehicle that can ride railroad rails"? Do you mean like a *train*?

Comment: Doesn't quite fit, but Emergence by David R. Palmer?

Comment: Actually, it fits perfectly with *Emergence*.  The boy converted the van the girl had driven on her search to be able to ride the rails, similarly to the rail trucks that railroad crews have used for many years.  The book is only about 30 years old, though.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183906/story-id-a-pre-teen-girl-who-is-a-genius-crosses-the-country-in-a-van (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 13):

This sounds very much like *[Emergence](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2300.Emergence)* (1984) by David Palmer. Blurb from Goodreads:

> Candidia Maria Smith-Foster, an eleven-year-old girl, is unaware that she's a Homo post hominem, mankind's next evolutionary step.
>
> With international relations rapidly deteriorating, Candy's father, publicly a small-town pathologist but secretly a government biowarfare expert, is called to Washington. Candy remains at home.
>
> The following day a worldwide attack, featuring a bionuclear plague, wipes out virtually all of humanity (i.e., Homo sapiens). With her pet bird Terry, she survives the attack in the shelter beneath their house. Emerging three months later, she learns of her genetic heritage and sets off to search for others of her kind.

The teenage boy in the book is called Adam and is an accomplished pianist, cook, driver and mechanic etc.

[image: "Emergence" book cover, line character on a road]

Comment: Why are those two works similar?

Comment: I was getting there. Hit post by mistake.

Comment: That happens :) Might want to add a link, if you find one - ISFDB might be a good bet.

Comment: This was my thought too. As I recall, the boy doesn't really pun much, but he has a habit of reversing words - like he says he "remantled" something he'd previously dismantled.

Comment: I recall that the boy and girl meet when he hits her with a race car.  She spends a lot of time recovering, which might be the poster's memory of her being in a coma.

Comment: As I recall, she was in a coma after the car accident - fortunately the boy has some medical training and was able to care for her while she was unconscious (which lasted long enough that he needed to keep her cleaned and fed (via IV).